# Use jquery to dynamically create a file path based on the id of a link users click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to build a dynamic path to specific json files on click of several links. This is for a restaurant menu. When a user clicks a link I want to have the json data returned an parsed in to html inside a div. I have that part working, but when I try to change the path of the json file I get a 404 error with a blank.json file does not exist. Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.linki').click(function(){
  var gJsn = this.id;
  $.getJSON( 'json/'+gJsn+'.json', function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    console.log(key + ' ' + val + ' ' + gJsn);
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( ".menuHere" );
});
});
});
```

specifically the problem lies here on line four:

```
$.getJSON( 'json/'+gJsn+'.json', function( data ) {
```

Getting the json file with a specific path works just fine:

```
$.getJSON( 'json/soups.json', function( data ) {
```

So what am I doing wrong? I thought `this.id` would work just fine. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my navigation menu code:

```
<nav>
  <ul  class="nav">
    <li id="soup" class="menu-item menu-item-21"><a href="#soup" class="linki">Soup</a></li>
    <li id="appetizers" class="menu-item menu-item-26"><a href="#appetizers" class="linki">Appetizers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-25"><a href="#events" class="linki">Family Style Dinners</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-29"><a href="#suppliers" class="linki">Mu-Shu</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki" class="linki">Fried Rice</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki" class="linki">Chow Mein</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki" class="linki">Pan Fried Noodle</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki" class="linki">Chow Fun</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki" class="linki">Drinks</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Egg Fu Yung</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Sizzling Entree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Vegetable Entree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Pork Entree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Prawn Entree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Lunch Specials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Chef's Specials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Chicken Entree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-231"><a href="#andy-hilton" class="linki">Beef Entree</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also, one item I would like to identify is how to remove the previously json data and load the new one when an item is clicked? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: My guess is that the element with class `linki` does not have the idea that you are expecting.

Comment: It does: `<li id="soup" class="menu-item menu-item-21"><a href="#soup" class="linki">Soup</a></li>` thanks, I will edit to show my nav menu:

Comment: li id is "soup" but your josn file has "soups"

Comment: @AtlanteAvila, try it now. I made a correction.

Comment: Hi JAG thanks for your reply, but that was also not the problem. The error I'm getting is a 404: `GET http://localhost:9000/json/.json 404 (Not Found)` I did fix what you pointed out though... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
var gJsn = this.id;
```

to

```
var gJsn = $(this).closest('.menu-item').attr('id');
```

Comment: hi AmmarCSE, thanks for your post, I tried your code and I get another 404: `GET http://localhost:9000/json/undefined.json 404 (Not Found)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @AmmarCSE that did it! Any idea how to remove the old data and load the new one as the items are clicked through so that only one set of menu items appear? Thanks!

Comment: @AtlanteAvila, Im not sure what you mean. If this is a different question, you should ask a new question. Glad I was able to help!